# Reading integer values stored as their ascii characters in java

Tags: java, file, io, ascii

the raw rgb data format from ImageMagick is basicaly some integers saved in to a file as ascii values. e.g. when it stores 42 and i open the date in an simple text editor i see " * " in that position (or 36->$ ...).
I want to read this values into a java program. I already tried something like:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));          
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {                
    for (int i=0;i<sCurrentLine.length();i++) {
        char chr = sCurrentLine.charAt(i);
        int ascii = (int) chr;
    }
}
```

this way i can read the values as they are but there are problems for some specific characters like new line (NL ascii:10) or similar.
is there a better way to read such a file like binary read or something?

Comment: Just don't use `readLine()`. Use `read()`. But this looks more like bytes than characters. So you should use an InputStream.

Comment: @JBNizet An `mmap`ed `Reader` would probably be even better.

Answer (score 1):

```
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:/temp/test.png"));
```

A byte being a value between -128 and 127 (signed). For an unsigned value:

```
int value = bytes[i] & 0xFF;
```

---

Now java is a bit special, in that char and String hold Unicode text, so FileReader does a conversion from the default platform encoding of the bytes in the file. Beside being inefficient, on a Linux server the default encoding could be UTF-8, a multi-byte encoding. That would fail, not giving a one-to-one correspondence between char and byte. On Western-Europe Windows a special quote could become a high Unicode char > 255.

So better not use char/String/Reader/Writer for pure binary data.